# PHP: How to delete last N bytes from large file?

Tags: php, large-files

I have a **large** file and need to delete last 512 bytes. I don't want to duplicate file.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you read the file into memory?

Comment: @alexn: Probably not a good idea.

Comment: @BoltClock large enough not to do a copy of it or @alexn not to read the file into memory

Comment: @BoltClock probably not, but how can we be sure if we don't know the filesize and memory limits?

Comment: @alexn if we don't know the filesize and memory limits it is not a good idea for sure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `ftruncate(handle, file_size - 512)` (get the file size with `filesize` or `fstat` function)

Comment: @profitphp Havenot tested it with real large files yet, but with files 200-300 Mb works fine.

Comment: Doesn't it load the whole file in memory except the last 512 bytes?

Answer (score 3):

Usage example with `fstat`, `ftruncate`, `fopen` and `fclose`:

```
<?php    

$bytesToTruncate = 5; // how many bytes we are going to delete from the end of the file

$handle = fopen('/home/francesco/mytest', 'r+'); // Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.

$stat = fstat($handle);
$size = $stat['size'] - $bytesToTruncate;
$size = $size < 0 ? 0 : $size;

ftruncate($handle, $size);
fclose($handle);
```

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it with large files but you can give it a try:

- http://es.php.net/filesize
- http://es.php.net/ftruncate